# WebMvcTest is too greedy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I want to write a `WebMvcTest` test for a single controller in my Spring Boot application. Among other things there are some custom `Converters` in my application. Although they are not needed for this particular controller that I want to test, Spring tries to create them anyway.

Now the problem: those custom converters require more beans from my application which are not initialised by `WebMvcTest` test slice. And don't want to mock tens of beans which are completely irrelevant for the particular test. Apart from specifying them all manually in `excludeFilters`, what are best practises for excluding some web components from specific `WebMvcTest` tests?

Comment: The best practice is to use `excludeFilters`. Why have you excluded that as a possible solution? A single controller-specific exclude filter is probably your most elegant option.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson First, adding similar `excludeFilters` to many tests is cumbersome.  Second, whenever we add a new converter, we will have to update all tests to add one more exclude. We prefer to structure code by "domain", so there is no single package to exclude.

Comment: You should be able to avoid that by creating your own annotation that is meta-annotated with `@WebMvcTest` and applies your custom filter. That custom filter would then be the one place that needs to be updated whenever a new converter is introduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom exclude filter in order to avoid loading converters into application context:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = YourController.class, excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = CUSTOM, classes = NoConvertersFilter.class))
public class YourControllerTest {
...
}

class NoConvertersFilter extends TypeExcludeFilter {

    private static final String CONVERTER_INTERFACE_NAME = Converter.class.getName();

    @Override
    public boolean match(@NonNull final MetadataReader metadataReader, @NonNull final MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory) throws IOException {

        return Arrays.asList(metadataReader.getClassMetadata().getInterfaceNames()).contains(CONVERTER_INTERFACE_NAME);
    }
}
```

With this approach you just have to add the excludeFilter to those controllers in which you don't want to have Converters loaded. No worries if a new converter is added: it'll be automatically excluded as far as it implements the converter interface.

Answer (score 0):

For custom tests don't use WebMvcTest, create a custom configuration:

```
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(value = SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SomeYourTestConfiguration.class})
public class TestClass {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        var someController = new SomeController();
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(someController).addFilters(...) 
            .setMessageConverters(...).setControllerAdvice(...).setValidator(...);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        //arrange
        when(...).thenReturn(...);
        //act
        var response = mockMvc.perform(...).andReturn().getResponse();
        //assert
        ...
    }
}
```

You can configure your `mockMvc` how you want.

Comment: why shouldn't WebMvcTest be used? If I want to create a test slice that loads only the controllers that I need, how am I supposed to achieve this with SpringBootTest? You proposal would potentially force me to use @MockBean on dozens of components, correct?